# Creating a qt GUI in Noetic and issues with catkin_create_qt_pkg

Tags: qt, user-interface, ros

I would like to create a QT GUI package in Noetic. Previously in kinetic/melodic, this could be done using the command 'catkin_create_qt_pkg ' but it's not working in Ubuntu 20.04 as I get

```
catkin_create_qt_pkg: command not found
```

Unfortunately, noetic appears to have removed the support for the qt-create and qt-build. Thus, I get 'Unable to locate package' when I try to install them using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-qt-build
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-qt-create
```

how to create a qt-gui in ubuntu-20.04 with noetic?

System info

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Kernel
- 5.10.0-1050-oem

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue. Try to make use of another template like this one: https://github.com/alexspirou/ROS_Melodic_Qt_GUI_Template

Comment: Qt and ROS support cmake. In Qt CMakelists, add the path for ros. This is the way I do it.

Comment: @CroCo Oh, I see. Would you please share more details on how do you do it manually?